# Requirement for a Master Key for Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have read in various MSDN pages and SQL Server blogs that "usually" a Master Key is required in a Service Broker database.

Indeed, when trying to RECEIVE messages I get the following application event log message:

> Service Broker needs to access the
>   master key in the database
>   'MDR_REPLICATION_Z'. Error code:26.
>   The master key has to exist and the
>   service master key encryption is
>   required.

What confuses me is why this is happening when all my CONVERSATIONs have ENCRYPTION = OFF.

Is there a way to make use of Service Broker internally within a single database where ENCYRPTION is OFF without having to create a Database Master Key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

Even though the target service specified in my **BEGIN** DIALOG is contained in the same database, I needed to be **explicit** about the fact that the **target** service was within the same database.

This is done by adding the optional **`CURRENT DATABASE`** when specifying the target service:

```
BEGIN DIALOG @dlg_handle 
FROM SERVICE CheckpointAndLogInitiatorService 
TO
SERVICE 'CheckpointAndLogTargetService', 'CURRENT DATABASE'
ON CONTRACT
CheckpointStart_CheckpointStartReply
WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;
```

Answer (score 4):

From [Service Broker Dialog Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166036.aspx):

> Service Broker dialog security lets
>   your application use authentication,
>   authorization, or encryption for an
>   individual dialog conversation (or
>   dialog). By default, all dialog
>   conversations use dialog security.
>   When you begin a dialog, you can
>   explicitly allow a dialog to proceed
>   without dialog security by including
>   the ENCRYPTION = OFF clause on the
>   BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION statement.
>   However, if a remote service binding
>   exists for the service that the
>   conversation targets, the dialog uses
>   security even when ENCRYPTION = OFF.

In other words, make sure you don't have any matching remote service bindings.

Comment: No remote servince bindings exist so this doesn't explain it.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative would be creating a **master key** for the service broker.

First Check your service broker queue by right clicking the queue and View Transmission Queue
or simply use this query

```
SELECT  *, casted_message_body = CASE message_type_name WHEN 'X' 
    THEN CAST(message_body AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
    ELSE message_body 
END 
FROM [DATABASE_NAME].[sys].[transmission_queue]
```

If you find any data in here then transmission_status column will have the reason for this.

If the broker is not playing its role, I would create NEW_BROKER with following query

```
USE [master] 
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE_NAME] SET NEW_BROKER
```

Then Enable the BROKER with TRUSTWORTHY set to ON

```
ALTER DATABASE DATABASE_NAME SET ENABLE_BROKER;
ALTER DATABASE DATABASE_NAME SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

Finally, dropping the master key and Creating New master key and encrypt by new password:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::DATABASE_NAME TO [SA];
DROP MASTER KEY
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '79HGKJ67ghjgk^&*^fgj'
GO
```

Password could be a user defined mixture of alphanumeric and symbols.

If any of the above steps taking longer time to run, then I would suggest you to stop the query and reopen the SQL manager and try again. It should work well!!